# See my weekly % rank when I only see my overall?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

Today I see my overall rank and yesterday I saw my week % rank. Is there a way to see my week rank today and if so, where?

Comment: Follow the link to see the reputation leagues.  Then click the appropriate tab for the different rankings.

Comment: But I can't see the % there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do the math for this yourself, but here's how you can find the numbers you'll need. Currently, there's no built-in way to find the percentage.

Click the "top 27% overall" link on your profile, and you'll go to the rep leagues. Scroll to the top and you'll find navigation tabs. Click the "Weekly" tab.

[image]

Locate the search box and type your username. Note that if you get no results, it means you haven't gained any rep in the selected time period, so you're not on the league for that period. (For instance, you won't find me on the "Weekly" league at the moment.

[image]

This'll give you your numerical ranking.

[image]

If you clear the search and go to the last page of the list, you'll find how many positions there are for your selected timeframe, in this case it'll be for this week. Do a little math, and you'll have your *current* percentage for the period. This percentage is subject to change, and likely frequently.

Comment: According to my calc, it's =27285/500000 = approx top 5 % (?) since there are 5 million users and my week rank is 27285. Do you agree?

Comment: @Programmer400 Not exactly, *users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues* so you would need to calculate based on the users with more than 200 rep.

Comment: @Programmer400 I actually covered that in the last paragraph- Clear your search for yourself and go to the last page of the weekly list to get the denominator for your calculation, since you're looking for your percentage _in_ the league.